# undefined method in nested resources has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I use rails 4.02. (strong_params)

3 models:

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :location
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
end
```

View:

```
- @region.cities.each do |city|
  %ol
    %li
      %h4.block-title-5
        = link_to city.name, country_region_city_path(city.region.country, city.region, city)
      %p
        = city.city_h2
      %p
        = city.location.latitude
```

I get the error-message `undefined method "latitude"`

this is the full-trace:

```
activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:13:in each' activerecord 
(4.0.3) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:13:in each' actionpack (4.0.3) 
lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in block in render' activesupport (4.0.3) 
lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in instrument' actionpack (4.0.3) 
lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in render' actionpack (4.0.3) 
lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:49:in block (2 levels) in render_template'
```

What am i doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: did `locations/Location` `table/model` has any `latitude` column/attribute

Comment: There is nothing seems wrong in your code. Please update complete error trace. Also add `belongs_to :region` in city. one more thing you should have city_id in location table to make it work'

Comment: yes the location table has attribute latitude. i updated the question with the log

Comment: activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:13:in `each'
activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:13:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in

Comment: it is unreadable Please post it in your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Location` model really has a `latitude` attribute, the most likely cause for this error is that you have some `City` records in your database that have nil values for `location`. You can check whether this is the case by looking at the full exception message, is it something like?:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `latitude' for nil:NilClass
```

In that case you have two choices depending on whether you consider `latitude` to be a required attribute for your `City` model or not. If its required then enforce that rule by adding a validation rule to your `City` model:

```
validates :location, presence: true
```

and perhaps a not null constraint to the foreign key column in the database schema.

Alternatively if missing `latitude` values are permitted in your application you can just handle the missing values in your view:

```
= city.location.try(:latitude)
```

Comment: your wright steve ...there were some records with nil values. Thanks..it works now!